# Memento in java. Mutable state

Tags: java, memento

I am trying to understand the Memento Pattern. For that purpose i am trying to implement the undo function. The problem is that when ever i save the old state of the originator in the queue and run a different function the save state changes to the current state. I really need help to understand what i am doing wrong. How can i make the vector to be immutable.

This is the memento class.

```
package memento;

public class Memento
{
    private final boolean[] vectorState;

    public Memento(boolean[] vector) {vectorState = vector;}

    boolean[] getMemento() { return vectorState;}

}
```

The Originator just need to shift a vector of boolean to the left.
(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE) shift left returns: (FALSE,FALSE,TRUE). This is the implementation.

```
package memento;

public class ShilftLeftOriginator
{
    private boolean[] vector;

    public ShilftLeftOriginator(boolean[] vector) {this.vector = vector;}

    public void execute()
    {
        final boolean firstValue = this.vector[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < this.vector.length; i++) {
            this.vector[i - 1] = this.vector[i];
        }
        this.vector[vector.length - 1] = firstValue;
    }


    public Memento saveToMemento() {return new Memento(vector);}

}
```

And the caretaker:

```
package memento;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public final class BooleanVector {
    private boolean[] vector;
    private Deque<Memento> mementoList = new LinkedList<>();

    public BooleanVector(boolean[] inputValues) {
        this.vector = inputValues;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) 
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof BooleanVector)) return false;
        BooleanVector otherVector = (BooleanVector) obj;
        return Arrays.equals(this.vector, otherVector.vector);
    }

    public void shiftLeft() 
    {
        ShilftLeftOriginator shiftLeft = new ShilftLeftOriginator(vector);
        mementoList.add(shiftLeft.saveToMemento());
        shiftLeft.execute(); // This is my Problem. After execute ist call the value(vector) in mementoList changes             
    }

    public void undo(){ this.vector =  mementoList.pop().getMemento();}

}
```

And now the test class and the error that i am receiving.

```
package memento;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] inputValues = { false, true, false };
        BooleanVector vector = new BooleanVector(inputValues);

        vector.shiftLeft();

        boolean[] expectedValues = new boolean[] { true, false, false };
        BooleanVector expectedVector = new BooleanVector(expectedValues);

        if (!vector.equals(expectedVector)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(vector.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("shiftleft working");
        }

        vector.undo();

        expectedValues = new boolean[] { false, true, false };
        expectedVector = new BooleanVector(expectedValues);

        if (!vector.equals(expectedVector)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(vector.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("undo working");
        }

    }

}
```

The console output:

```
shiftleft working
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: [true, false, false]
    at memento.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're always manipulating the same array. So if you shift left, you also shift left the array you stored in the `Memento` object, because it's all the same array.

To solve it, make a copy of the array in the constructor of the `Memento` object:

```
public Memento(boolean[] vector) {
    vectorState = Arrays.copyOf(vector, vector.length);
}
```

Aside from that, you seem to have your classes mixed up. `BooleanVector` and `ShilftLeftOriginator` are the originator, while `Main` is the caretaker.

Comment: Thank you very much that was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a little bit more expandable solution:

**class Originator:** *abstract implementatino of the value `T` holder*

```
public abstract class Originator<T> {

    private T value;
    private final CareTaker<T> careTaker;

    protected Originator(T value, CareTaker<T> careTaker) {
        this.value = value;
        this.careTaker = careTaker;
    }

    public final T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    protected final void setValue(T value) {
        careTaker.add(this.value);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public final void undo() {
        if (!careTaker.isEmpty())
            value = careTaker.remove();
    }

}
```

**class BooleanVector:** *concrete implementation that holds `boolean[]`*

```
public final class BooleanVector extends Originator<boolean[]> {

    public BooleanVector(boolean[] obj) {
        super(obj, new CareTaker<>());
    }

    public void leftShift() {
        if (getValue() == null || getValue().length == 0)
            return;

        boolean[] arr = new boolean[getValue().length];
        boolean tmp = arr[0];
        System.arraycopy(getValue(), 1, arr, 0, getValue().length - 1);
        arr[arr.length - 1] = tmp;
        setValue(arr);
    }

}
```

**class CareTaker:** *implementation of values change history - memento*

```
public final class CareTaker<T> {

    private final Deque<Item<T>> stack = new LinkedList<>();

    public void add(T value) {
        stack.push(new Item<>(value));
    }

    public T remove() {
        return stack.pop().data;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return stack.isEmpty();
    }

    private static final class Item<T> {

        private final T data;

        public Item(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BooleanVector originator = new BooleanVector(new boolean[] { false, true, false });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originator.getValue()));
    System.out.println("---");
    originator.leftShift();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originator.getValue()));
    originator.undo();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(originator.getValue()));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[false, true, false]
---
[true, false, false]
[false, true, false]
```